# Close TCP Connection

Tags: networking

I am trying to create a bash script to close any "Established" connection through e,g. "port 445" but I didn't have success.

The experience that I want to have is this:

If i am connected to an application/game, I wish to have a "kick" from the application/game only (No close the application, only TCP disconnections for a few seconds), If I try to reconnect, I must can.

I tried to do it with iptables (closing the output e,g. "port 445") but it kicked me pretty slowly.
Also I tried with tcpkill tool but it can't kill the tcp connections that are already "established", only the new ones.
Last but not least, I tried with "Cutter" tool but I coudln't use it properly, it showed me this message (openning ip_conntrack or nf_conntrack (is kernel module 'conntrack' loaded?): No such file or directory) after introduce this command: *cutter [IP] [Port]*

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04**

I know that this may sound weird but ... on Windows there are many applications like this, they call it as "Smart Exit", Proxies offers this kind of tools: Noping, Tibiatunnel, etc.

If someone can help me with this, give me an idea or knows more about how to install and use "cutter" tool on **Ubuntu 18.04**, I will appreciate it.

Regards!

Comment: Why not just reject all connections to that port using iptables?

Comment: Sorry, what you mean?, reject connections with iptables and then accept it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible since sockets are usually tied to specific process. So unless it has a mechanism of listening to user and closing a socket, there's no way.  Maybe reloading firewall rules periodically could work but I'm not sure if that requires closing a process or not

Comment: Well, I was thinking on create a shortcut to control this KICKS (disconnections), have you used CUTTER tool?

Comment: What's the end goal here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I already tested rejecting with iptables but DROP and REJECT have the same behavior.

Comment: Muru...

Could you check this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpPaGwjIZb4

Please check how this guy use a tool to be kicked from the game easily.

I want something similar but on Linux

Comment: I'll look into this. I don't think there's an easy way though.

Comment: Hello there Muru, Sergiy, any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I use "dsniff" to achieve this, I created 2 bash scripts, the first one listen a TCP connection on a specific port, if it found a TCP connection, it will cut that connection, the second one stops the bash script that is listening the connections on a specific port.

To make it easy, I use 2 Keyboard Shortcuts to start/stop the bash scripts.

I really appreciate the help of this community.

Thanks!